# Binding to Xaml

Tags: xaml, mvvm, binding

I am binding a model to my Xaml code and have a question about how to bind to a Property.

Let's assume my View Model looks like

```
internal class LogsVM
{
    private List<Log> logList;
    public List<Log> LogList
    {
        get; set;
    }       

    public LogsVM()
    {

    }

    public LogsVM(List<Logging.Log> logs)
    {
        logList = logs;
    }
}
```

and assume my Log class looks like

```
internal class Log
{
    public string Title { get;set; }
    public List<MoreDetails> moreDetails;

    public Log()
    {
        moreDetails= new List<MoreDetails>();
    }
}
```

In Xaml, how do I bind to the Title within a TreeView?

My Xaml so far looks like

```
<Window x:Class="BackUps.Logging.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:myData ="clr-namespace:BackUps.Logging.ViewModel"
        Title="Logging Results" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <myData:LogsVM x:Key="Vm" />
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.DataContext>
            <Binding Source="{StaticResource Vm}"></Binding>
        </Grid.DataContext>
        <TreeView>
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type myData:LogsVM}" ItemsSource="{Binding LogList}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type myData:LogsVM}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding moreDetails.Staus}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And my MainWindow code behind

```
public MainWindow(List<Log> logs)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LogsVM logVm = new LogsVM(logs);
        this.DataContext = logVm;
    }
```

As you can see in the above code, I'm trying to bind the Title property but my screen doesn't display an text at all.

So, my 2 questions are:

1. Is it enough to use my ViewModel class alone or do I also need to tell the Xaml each internal class of the ViewModel (in this case, the Log class)? EG

   xmlns:myData ="clr-namespace:BackUps.Logging.ViewModel"
   xmlns:moreData = "clr-namespace:BackUps.Logging.Logs"
2. What do I need to do to bind the Title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Binding` is not complicated as you might think, Your are just not mastering the `Treeview`'s `HierarchicalDataTemplate` stuff and exposing properties to the `XAML`,
set your all your domain classes public cause they are used in public properties.
myData should reference the domain classes namespace.for ex: in my case `xmlns:myData="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"` `MoreDetails` has to be a public property in `Log` class.

```
   <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding LogList}" >
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type myData:Log}" ItemsSource="{Binding MoreDetails}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type myData:MoreDetails}" >
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>



public class Log
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public List<MoreDetails> MoreDetails { get; set; }

        public Log()
        {
            MoreDetails = new List<MoreDetails>();
        }
    }

    public class MoreDetails
    {
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }

public class YourVM
{
     public YourVM() // in my case i've just run it fast in code behind 
            {
                LogList = new List<Log>
                    {
                        new Log{Title = "Hichem", MoreDetails = new List<MoreDetails>{ new MoreDetails{Status = "OK"}}},
                        new Log{Title = "Hichem"},
                        new Log{Title = "Hichem"},
                        new Log{Title = "Hichem"},
                    };

            }


            public List<Log> LogList { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Unless all the data is going to be static this should also include change notification, with INotifyPropertyChanged on both classes and ObservableCollection instead of List.

Comment: Exactly, I just didnt want to add "out of case" features to the current code

Comment: Thank you for answering. Can I assume though your code is using just 1 namespace? The problem I think I have is my Log is part of BackUps.Logging namespace, and my ViewModel is part of my BackUps.Logging.ViewModels namespace... or should this make no difference?

Comment: Yes I am, you don't need to use the VM's namespace since you're already setting the DataContext in code behind, You just need the namespace contains your business classes to retrieve just Types needed forex Log type in : `DataType="{x:Type myTypes:Log}"` needs `xmlns:myTypes="clr-namespace:BackUps.Logging"` to be set.

Comment: Thank you @HichemC for taking the time. The issue I had was I was binding via the code behind and in my xaml and so getting unexpected results!! Thank you